# Trying to add a new column

Tags: android, searchable

guys, I'm trying to add a new column (KEY_EXAMPLE) in my "searchable dictionary" code example

The KEY_EXAMPLE should be the third column. But it doesn't work....

Here is my code:

DictionaryDatabase.Java

```
public class DictionaryDatabase {
private static final String TAG = "DictionaryDatabase";

//The columns we'll include in the dictionary table
public static final String KEY_WORD = SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1;
public static final String KEY_DEFINITION = SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_2;
public static final String KEY_EXAMPLE = SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1;

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dictionary";
private static final String FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE = "FTSdictionary";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

private final DictionaryOpenHelper mDatabaseOpenHelper;
private static final HashMap<String,String> mColumnMap = buildColumnMap();

/**
 * Constructor
 * @param context The Context within which to work, used to create the DB
 */
public DictionaryDatabase(Context context) {
    mDatabaseOpenHelper = new DictionaryOpenHelper(context);
}

/**
 * Builds a map for all columns that may be requested, which will be given to the 
 * SQLiteQueryBuilder. This is a good way to define aliases for column names, but must include 
 * all columns, even if the value is the key. This allows the ContentProvider to request
 * columns w/o the need to know real column names and create the alias itself.
 */
private static HashMap<String,String> buildColumnMap() {
    HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
    map.put(KEY_WORD, KEY_WORD);
    map.put(KEY_DEFINITION, KEY_DEFINITION);
    map.put(KEY_EXAMPLE, KEY_EXAMPLE);
    map.put(BaseColumns._ID, "rowid AS " +
            BaseColumns._ID);
    map.put(SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID, "rowid AS " +
            SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID);
    map.put(SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_SHORTCUT_ID, "rowid AS " +
            SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_SHORTCUT_ID);
    return map;
}

/**
 * Returns a Cursor positioned at the word specified by rowId
 *
 * @param rowId id of word to retrieve
 * @param columns The columns to include, if null then all are included
 * @return Cursor positioned to matching word, or null if not found.
 */
public Cursor getWord(String rowId, String[] columns) {
    String selection = "rowid = ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {rowId};

    return query(selection, selectionArgs, columns);

    /* This builds a query that looks like:
     *     SELECT <columns> FROM <table> WHERE rowid = <rowId>
     */
}

/**
 * Returns a Cursor over all words that match the given query
 *
 * @param query The string to search for
 * @param columns The columns to include, if null then all are included
 * @return Cursor over all words that match, or null if none found.
 */
public Cursor getWordMatches(String query, String[] columns) {
    String selection = KEY_WORD + " MATCH ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {query+"*"};

    return query(selection, selectionArgs, columns);

    /* This builds a query that looks like:
     *     SELECT <columns> FROM <table> WHERE <KEY_WORD> MATCH 'query*'
     * which is an FTS3 search for the query text (plus a wildcard) inside the word column.
     *
     * - "rowid" is the unique id for all rows but we need this value for the "_id" column in
     *    order for the Adapters to work, so the columns need to make "_id" an alias for "rowid"
     * - "rowid" also needs to be used by the SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA alias in order
     *   for suggestions to carry the proper intent data.
     *   These aliases are defined in the DictionaryProvider when queries are made.
     * - This can be revised to also search the definition text with FTS3 by changing
     *   the selection clause to use FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE instead of KEY_WORD (to search across
     *   the entire table, but sorting the relevance could be difficult.
     */
}

/**
 * Performs a database query.
 * @param selection The selection clause
 * @param selectionArgs Selection arguments for "?" components in the selection
 * @param columns The columns to return
 * @return A Cursor over all rows matching the query
 */
private Cursor query(String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String[] columns) {
    /* The SQLiteBuilder provides a map for all possible columns requested to
     * actual columns in the database, creating a simple column alias mechanism
     * by which the ContentProvider does not need to know the real column names
     */
    SQLiteQueryBuilder builder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    builder.setTables(FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE);
    builder.setProjectionMap(mColumnMap);

    Cursor cursor = builder.query(mDatabaseOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(),
            columns, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);

    if (cursor == null) {
        return null;
    } else if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        cursor.close();
        return null;
    }
    return cursor;
}


/**
 * This creates/opens the database.
 */
private static class DictionaryOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private final Context mHelperContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;

    /* Note that FTS3 does not support column constraints and thus, you cannot
     * declare a primary key. However, "rowid" is automatically used as a unique
     * identifier, so when making requests, we will use "_id" as an alias for "rowid"
     */
    private static final String FTS_TABLE_CREATE =
                "CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE " + FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE +
                " USING fts3 (" +
                KEY_WORD + ", " +
                KEY_DEFINITION + ", " +
                KEY_EXAMPLE + " );";

    DictionaryOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        mHelperContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        mDatabase = db;
        mDatabase.execSQL(FTS_TABLE_CREATE);
        loadDictionary();
    }

    /**
     * Starts a thread to load the database table with words
     */
    private void loadDictionary() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    loadWords();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    private void loadWords() throws IOException {
        Log.d(TAG, "Loading words...");
        final Resources resources = mHelperContext.getResources();
        InputStream inputStream = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.definitions);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        try {
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] strings = TextUtils.split(line, "//");
                if (strings.length < 2) continue;
                long id = addWord(strings[0].trim(), strings[1].trim(), strings[2].trim());
                if (id < 0) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "unable to add word: " + strings[0].trim());
                }
            }
        } finally {
            reader.close();
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "DONE loading words.");
    }

    /**
     * Add a word to the dictionary.
     * @return rowId or -1 if failed
     */
    public long addWord(String word, String definition, String example) {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_WORD, word);
        initialValues.put(KEY_DEFINITION, definition);
        initialValues.put(KEY_EXAMPLE, example);
        return mDatabase.insert(FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}

}
```

DictionaryProvider.java

```
public class DictionaryProvider extends ContentProvider {
String TAG = "DictionaryProvider";

public static String AUTHORITY = "com.example.android.searchabledict.DictionaryProvider";
public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + "/dictionary");

// MIME types used for searching words or looking up a single definition
public static final String WORDS_MIME_TYPE = ContentResolver.CURSOR_DIR_BASE_TYPE +
                                              "/vnd.example.android.searchabledict";
public static final String DEFINITION_MIME_TYPE = ContentResolver.CURSOR_ITEM_BASE_TYPE +
                                                   "/vnd.example.android.searchabledict";

private DictionaryDatabase mDictionary;

// UriMatcher stuff
private static final int SEARCH_WORDS = 0;
private static final int GET_WORD = 1;
private static final int SEARCH_SUGGEST = 2;
private static final int REFRESH_SHORTCUT = 3;
private static final UriMatcher sURIMatcher = buildUriMatcher();

/**
 * Builds up a UriMatcher for search suggestion and shortcut refresh queries.
 */
private static UriMatcher buildUriMatcher() {
    UriMatcher matcher =  new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
    // to get definitions...
    matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "dictionary", SEARCH_WORDS);
    matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "dictionary/#", GET_WORD);
    // to get suggestions...
    matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_QUERY, SEARCH_SUGGEST);
    matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_QUERY + "/*", SEARCH_SUGGEST);

    /* The following are unused in this implementation, but if we include
     * {@link SearchManager#SUGGEST_COLUMN_SHORTCUT_ID} as a column in our suggestions table, we
     * could expect to receive refresh queries when a shortcutted suggestion is displayed in
     * Quick Search Box, in which case, the following Uris would be provided and we
     * would return a cursor with a single item representing the refreshed suggestion data.
     */
    matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_SHORTCUT, REFRESH_SHORTCUT);
    matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_SHORTCUT + "/*", REFRESH_SHORTCUT);
    return matcher;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreate() {
    mDictionary = new DictionaryDatabase(getContext());
    return true;
}

/**
 * Handles all the dictionary searches and suggestion queries from the Search Manager.
 * When requesting a specific word, the uri alone is required.
 * When searching all of the dictionary for matches, the selectionArgs argument must carry
 * the search query as the first element.
 * All other arguments are ignored.
 */
@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs,
                    String sortOrder) {

    // Use the UriMatcher to see what kind of query we have and format the db query accordingly
    switch (sURIMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case SEARCH_SUGGEST:
            if (selectionArgs == null) {
              throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                  "selectionArgs must be provided for the Uri: " + uri);
            }
            return getSuggestions(selectionArgs[0]);
        case SEARCH_WORDS:
            if (selectionArgs == null) {
              throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                  "selectionArgs must be provided for the Uri: " + uri);
            }
            return search(selectionArgs[0]);
        case GET_WORD:
            return getWord(uri);
        case REFRESH_SHORTCUT:
            return refreshShortcut(uri);
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown Uri: " + uri);
    }
}

private Cursor getSuggestions(String query) {
  query = query.toLowerCase();
  String[] columns = new String[] {
      BaseColumns._ID,
      DictionaryDatabase.KEY_WORD,

   /* SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_SHORTCUT_ID,
                    (only if you want to refresh shortcuts) */
      SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID};

  return mDictionary.getWordMatches(query, columns);
}

private Cursor search(String query) {
  query = query.toLowerCase();
  String[] columns = new String[] {
      BaseColumns._ID,
      DictionaryDatabase.KEY_WORD,
      DictionaryDatabase.KEY_DEFINITION,
      DictionaryDatabase.KEY_EXAMPLE};

  return mDictionary.getWordMatches(query, columns);
}

private Cursor getWord(Uri uri) {
  String rowId = uri.getLastPathSegment();
  String[] columns = new String[] {
      DictionaryDatabase.KEY_WORD,
      DictionaryDatabase.KEY_DEFINITION,
      DictionaryDatabase.KEY_EXAMPLE};

  return mDictionary.getWord(rowId, columns);
}

private Cursor refreshShortcut(Uri uri) {
  /* This won't be called with the current implementation, but if we include
   * {@link SearchManager#SUGGEST_COLUMN_SHORTCUT_ID} as a column in our suggestions table, we
   * could expect to receive refresh queries when a shortcutted suggestion is displayed in
   * Quick Search Box. In which case, this method will query the table for the specific
   * word, using the given item Uri and provide all the columns originally provided with the
   * suggestion query.
   */
  String rowId = uri.getLastPathSegment();
  String[] columns = new String[] {
      BaseColumns._ID,
      DictionaryDatabase.KEY_WORD,
      DictionaryDatabase.KEY_DEFINITION,
      DictionaryDatabase.KEY_EXAMPLE,
      SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_SHORTCUT_ID,
      SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID};

  return mDictionary.getWord(rowId, columns);
}

/**
 * This method is required in order to query the supported types.
 * It's also useful in our own query() method to determine the type of Uri received.
 */
@Override
public String getType(Uri uri) {
    switch (sURIMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case SEARCH_WORDS:
            return WORDS_MIME_TYPE;
        case GET_WORD:
            return DEFINITION_MIME_TYPE;
        case SEARCH_SUGGEST:
            return SearchManager.SUGGEST_MIME_TYPE;
        case REFRESH_SHORTCUT:
            return SearchManager.SHORTCUT_MIME_TYPE;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URL " + uri);
    }
}

// Other required implementations...

@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}

@Override
public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}

@Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}

}
```

SearchableDictionary.java

```
public class SearchableDictionary extends Activity {

private TextView mTextView;
private ListView mListView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    handleIntent(getIntent());
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    // Because this activity has set launchMode="singleTop", the system calls this method
    // to deliver the intent if this activity is currently the foreground activity when
    // invoked again (when the user executes a search from this activity, we don't create
    // a new instance of this activity, so the system delivers the search intent here)
    handleIntent(intent);
}

private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        // handles a click on a search suggestion; launches activity to show word
        Intent wordIntent = new Intent(this, WordActivity.class);
        wordIntent.setData(intent.getData());
        startActivity(wordIntent);
    } else if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        // handles a search query
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        showResults(query);
    }
}

/**
 * Searches the dictionary and displays results for the given query.
 * @param query The search query
 */
private void showResults(String query) {

    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(DictionaryProvider.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
                            new String[] {query}, null);

    if (cursor == null) {
        // There are no results
        mTextView.setText(getString(R.string.no_results, new Object[] {query}));
    } else {
        // Display the number of results
        int count = cursor.getCount();
        String countString = getResources().getQuantityString(R.plurals.search_results,
                                count, new Object[] {count, query});
        mTextView.setText(countString);

        // Specify the columns we want to display in the result
        String[] from = new String[] { DictionaryDatabase.KEY_WORD,
                                       DictionaryDatabase.KEY_DEFINITION,
                                       DictionaryDatabase.KEY_EXAMPLE};

        // Specify the corresponding layout elements where we want the columns to go
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.word,
                               R.id.definition,
                               R.id.example};

        // Create a simple cursor adapter for the definitions and apply them to the ListView
        SimpleCursorAdapter words = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                                      R.layout.result, cursor, from, to);
        mListView.setAdapter(words);

        // Define the on-click listener for the list items
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // Build the Intent used to open WordActivity with a specific word Uri
                Intent wordIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WordActivity.class);
                Uri data = Uri.withAppendedPath(DictionaryProvider.CONTENT_URI,
                                                String.valueOf(id));
                wordIntent.setData(data);
                startActivity(wordIntent);
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    }

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.search:
            onSearchRequested();
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
}
```

WordActivity.java

```
public class WordActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.word);

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor == null) {
        finish();
    } else {
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        TextView word = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.word);
        TextView definition = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.definition);
        TextView example = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.example);

        int wIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DictionaryDatabase.KEY_WORD);
        int dIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DictionaryDatabase.KEY_DEFINITION);
        int eIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DictionaryDatabase.KEY_EXAMPLE);

        word.setText(cursor.getString(wIndex));
        definition.setText(cursor.getString(dIndex));
        example.setText(cursor.getString(eIndex));
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    }

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.search:
            onSearchRequested();
            return true;
        case android.R.id.home:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SearchableDictionary.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: "But it doesn't work" is pretty vague. Have you upped your database version and properly re-created the database in onUpdate?

Comment: Yes, I have. But it still doesn't work. Actually, I don't know why I can't use public static final String KEY_EXAMPLE = SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_3;

Comment: So, I put SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_2 or 1...because I had no choice.... the eclipse doesn't permit....

Comment: how about explaining what "doesn't work" means. MAybe even include logcat output with the errors you're having

Comment: @Martin The Third Column (KEY_EXAMPLE) doesn't exist. It doesn't work!

Comment: `SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_3` simply does not exist. you cannot create it.

Comment: @njzk2 So, what is your suggestion for that, anyway?

Comment: why are you using these column names in the first place?

Comment: Because I'm creating a personal dictionary with "word", "definition" and "example"....

Answer (score 0):

Close inspection reveals that you have the same string value assigned to 1 and 3

```
public static final String KEY_WORD = SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1;
public static final String KEY_DEFINITION = SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_2;
public static final String KEY_EXAMPLE = SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1;
```

Comment: @Matin I know Martin. But what should I do? Replace the string value for which one? SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_3 does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

it is a limitation that you can have only two items in the search suggestion provided by android

refer section

> **The biggest problem with search suggestions**

in http://www.grokkingandroid.com/android-tutorial-adding-suggestions-to-search/